# Unwanted Space in div tags

Tags: css, html, web

I have two div id's. One has has an image in it and the other has a background image. There is an unwanted space in between these two divs. In the dreamweaver design view it appears as if there is no space, but if I make it live or preview in browser the space appears again.

This is the css for the divs

```
#header {
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#content {
    background-image:url(img/ContentBox.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This is my body html (ignore the multiple line breaks, this is just so I can see the bg img in the div)

```
<body>

<div id="header"><img src="img/Header.jpg" /></div>
<div id="content"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images have a default display setting of `inline`. This causes them to flow inline with text, vertically-aligned with the baseline. All text is vertically-aligned with the baseline by default as well, unless you change it by setting `vertical-align` to something else on its containing element.

#### What is baseline?

The baseline floats above the bottom of the actual line. Look at the lower-case letter `g`. The bottom of the top circle is the baseline. That's where the images are getting aligned.

You can solve this multiple ways, but here are a couple:

#### Vertical Alignment

Again, image elements are set to `display: inline` by default. Assuming you don't want to change this, you need to adjust how the image element aligns vertically on the current line of text.

The `vertical-align` CSS property sets the vertical alignment of an inline element on the current line of text. *It doesn't set it relative to the container.*

Therefore, you can set the `vertical-align` property to `middle`, `top`, or `bottom`, and as long as the image element is larger than the `line-height` of the current line of text, it will not have the extra space below it.

However, you need to remember what I just said about `line-height`. In the event that your `line-height` is larger than your image element, `vertical-align` will do more than remove that extra spacing: it will actually align the image element on the line accordingly. [See this jsFiddle to see an example of how a `line-height` greater than the height of the image will affect the result.](http://jsfiddle.net/hWr66/)

So, keeping with the HTML that you provided, to set the vertical alignment, you'd do the following CSS rule:

```
#header img {
    vertical-align: bottom; /* or top or middle */
}
```

#### Displaying as Block Level

Another option would be to change the image element to display as a block level element. I don't recommend this approach unless you know you want a block level image.

Block level elements automatically fill to their container, and don't flow inline with text or other inline elements. Also, if you set a `float` on the image, this would force it to be `block` level.

So, you have two options to display as block level:

```
#header img {
    display: block;
}
```

or

```
#header img {
    float: left; /* You could float right too */
}
```

Comment: or vertical-align:top; the reason is that image, as inline-boxes stands on the baseline by default, just like letters does ... guess, there's a gap underneath ..

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I'm still really new to this. Would I do that in the html document or the external style sheet?

Comment: I added the Vertical-align: bottom to my #header, but that didn't solve the problem.

#header {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

Comment: @user3246575 You need to apply it the image element, not the #header. Try `#header img { vertical-align: bottom; }`. Ideally, you should give the image element a specific class, or all images in #header will get vertical-align set to bottom.

Comment: That's a good point @GCyrillus It actually defaults to `inline`, not `inline-block`. Either way, it would suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Okay thanks that makes a lot more sense. I completely forgot that I could set the css to only work on images inside that id. Thanks so much! I've been working on this for hours, lol.

Comment: @user3246575 No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow! (Don't forget to register your account)