# vertical align image and text in div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div which includes an image and text and they should be vertically aligned: middle, though I do not get it to work. Not sure what I did wrong.

Find below my Fiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwshE/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="social-cont">
    <div class="social-cont1">
        <img src="img/contact1.png" alt="contact1" width="21" height="30" />
    </div> <!-- end social-cont1 -->
    <div class="social-cont2">
        <h6 class="social-context">Pastoor de Leijerstraat 29, 5246JA, Hintham</h6>
    </div> <!-- end social-cont1 -->

</div> <!-- end social-cont -->

<div class="social-cont">
    <div class="social-cont1">
        <img src="img/contact3.png" alt="contact3" width="23" height="24" />
    </div> <!-- end social-cont1 -->
    <div class="social-cont2">
        <h6 class="social-context">XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h6>
    </div> <!-- end social-cont1 -->
</div> <!-- end social-cont -->
```

CSS

```
.social-cont {
    height: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    display: table;
    background-color: salmon;
}

.social-cont1 img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

h6.social-context {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #404040;
    float: left;
}
```

This is what I get when previewing the code in Coda:

[image: This is what I get when previewing the code in Coda]

Comment: Your post is incomplete. Please insert your Coda preview.

Comment: Insert your code from that jsFiddle, as the rules say.

Comment: `vertical-align` doesn't work on block level elements. You've floated your image element, which forces it to block level. Read my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418400/unwanted-space-in-div-tags/21418418#answer-21418418) to get a better understanding of how `vertical-align` works.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that you are setting the image to act as a `table-cell`. This isn't a good idea. You should set it's container to `table-cell` and leave the image as either `inline`, `inline-block`, or `block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `display: inline-block` and use `vertical-align: middle` on your container divs the content will be vertically aligned correctly.

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fwshE/2/)

```
.social-cont2,
.social-cont1{display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Edit: [**Fiddle using table-cell instead**](http://jsfiddle.net/fwshE/9/)

EDIT:  [**Fiddle with valid image files**](http://jsfiddle.net/c32js6vL/)

Comment: What if he wanted to use `table-cell` for the `display`?

Comment: @crush (s)he could of course change `display: inline-block;` to `display: table-cell;` if it's important that the content is displayed as tabular data. In this case however still having `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on the divs `.social-cont1 img` and `h6.social-context` is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `float: left` and in fact you don't need `.social-cont1` and `.social-cont2`, you can style `img` and `h6`

```
.social-cont1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.social-cont2 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #404040;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwshE/3/